# Solutions to exercises of Graph Theory and Its Applications, Second Edition by Gross, Jonathan L.

Tags: graph-theory, book-recommendation

I really like the book "Graph Theory and Its Applications, Second Edition" by Gross, Jonathan L., but I can't find the solutions to its exercises, even not on amazon. Can someone help me find it or recommend a good alternative that would cover graph theory without much prerequsites with solution manual available?

Comment: It is worth noting that many (most?) advanced math textbooks do not have solutions manuals prepared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for something elementary to teach yourself graph theory, I would recommend 'A walk through Combinatorics' by Miklos Bona. It has a good amount of problems and has solutions at the end of the chapter.